# How to use angular component file variable into js file

Tags: javascript, angular

I have one .js file in my angular project firebase-messaging-sw.js where I want to access the variable of one of my component.ts file

```
 messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {

 console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service to communicate between multiple components.

Comment: will that work between js and ts file, please share the sample code for that

Comment: If you are using angular components then I will request you to use ts only. Use the link to learn how to use service to communicate between two components. https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/communicating-across-components-using-services

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).